# how to move a pyspark installation

Tags: macos, pyspark

I'm an absolute newbie to Spark recently installed PySpark on my Mac to learn it. However, it seems that the build has been inadvertently installed in a specific directory (which I use for something else) and I can only call pyspark from within that directory using ./bin/pyspark. 
My question is: can i move the entire spark.1.5.1 directory that the build has created to some other location so I can call pyspark from anywhere without actually being in that location (just like I might call python)?
Thanks in advance,
K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could actually do that without moving spark: just add the path to executables to your `$PATH` environment variable. If you had any error while trying to call pyspark from outside that directory, please include it in your question.